# tikzcd : How to get even column spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have done the following

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
K_1 \arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{21}} & K_2\arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{32}} & 
K_3\arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{43}} & K_4\\
K_{01}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow{ur}{\beta_{21}}&
K_{02}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
K_{03}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{43}}&
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{4}} \\
\beta_{21}^{-1}(K_{02})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{21}} &
\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{3}}\\
\beta_{21}^{-1}\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{2}}\\   
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{1}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
```

and the columns are tighter and tighter from left to right. How to have even (cols and rows) spacing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is due to the unequal widths of the nodes.  There's an easy solution with `\mathclap` from `mathtools`  if you know how  to increase *individually*  the distance from arrows to nodes.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I'll have a look at pgf manual then. Is it the good place ?

Comment: Sure, but there's a lot of pages (nearly 1200…). But maybe soeone will find a solution. I don't know TikZ well enough to help in this respect. If you can consider using `pstricks`, I know how to do it.

Comment: @Bernard I will wait a bit. For the time being I have to stick to `TikZ`. I'd love to evolve to `pstricks` however. Do you know a good introduction ?

Comment: The documentations of the different modules are usually rather well done (in my opinion), and shorter than TikZ. You can take a look at the doecumentation of TUG India. There's a link on the [PSTricks web page](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=doc/docs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `between origins`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep={6em,between origins},
  row sep={6em,between origins},
]
K_1 \arrow[r,dashed,"\mu_{21}"] & K_2\arrow[r,dashed,"\mu_{32}"] &
K_3 \arrow[r,dashed,"\mu_{43}"] & K_4\\
K_{01} \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{21}"] &
K_{02} \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{32}"] &
K_{03} \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{43}"] &
R \arrow[u,swap,"\alpha_{4}"] \\
\beta_{21}^{-1}(K_{02}) \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{21}"] &
\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03}) \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{32}"] &
R \arrow[u,swap,"\alpha_{3}"] \\
\beta_{21}^{-1}\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03}) \arrow[u,hook] \arrow[ur,"\beta_{32}"] &
R \arrow[u,swap,"\alpha_{2}"] \\
R \arrow[u,swap,"\alpha_{1}"]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely I misunderstand something, but based on what Bernard was saying I'd do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        minimum width=1.8cm
    }}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
K_1 \arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{21}} & K_2\arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{32}} & 
K_3\arrow[dashed]{r}{\mu_{43}} & K_4\\
K_{01}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow{ur}{\beta_{21}}&
K_{02}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
K_{03}\arrow[hook]{u}\arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{43}}&
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{4}} \\
\beta_{21}^{-1}(K_{02})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{21}} &
\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{3}}\\
\beta_{21}^{-1}\beta_{32}^{-1}(K_{03})\arrow[hook]{u} \arrow[]{ur}{\beta_{32}} &
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{2}}\\   
R\arrow[swap]{u}{\alpha_{1}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you (and also for initial formatting), I adopted `between origins`which seems to match better with my environment (+1).